# Flutter BLoC I need Theme for init value

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

Inside my app.dart I have my BlocProviders:

```
  return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [      
           BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => SysUiCubit(context: context, "currentTheme: currentTheme"),
          ), child: MaterialApp(
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme.copyWith(brightness: Brightness.light),
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme.copyWith(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      themeMode: themeService.getSysMode ? ThemeMode.system : (themeService.getDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light),
```

and after my BlocProviders I have the MaterialApp. The problem is: For the SysUiCubit I need the state of the current theme like I tried to visualize inside the quotation mark. The easiest way would be to have the MaterialApp before my BlocProvider, but I think this isn't possible - isn't it?
To understand the use case: Inside my SysUiCubit I have a

```
  factory SysUiState.initial(BuildContext context){
    return  const SysUiState(systemUiOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
  }
```

Where I want to add an Overlaystyle dependent from the current theme. So as you can guess, to realize that inside the init state, the theme mode must already be set.
Any advice how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you added systemUiOverlayStyle as a required parameter I would suggest trying this solution:

1. in SysUiCubit constructor make systemUiOverlayStyle an optional parameter (no need to pass "currentTheme: currentTheme")
2. in SysUiCubit contractor check if systemUiOverlayStyle parameter is null, if it is full then check the shared preferences if the app stored the last theme (dark or light), if the shareprefrance is empty (mainly because the user opened the app for the first time) force a default theme based on the system theme (there are packages or system functions that retrieve the active theme).
3. whenever you want to change the theme, call bloc controller and update the value (systemUiOverlayStyle).
4. no need to change the order of the current widgets

let me know if you got my points.

Comment: Its just about the Init state, here I have problems. Inside my State I do this:

`class SysUiState {
  final SystemUiOverlayStyle? systemUiOverlayStyle;

  factory SysUiState.initial(){
    return  const SysUiState(null);
  }`

and now I try to work with the constructor from my Cubit: 
`class SysUiCubit extends Cubit<SysUiState> {
  final BuildContext context;

  SysUiCubit({required this.context}) : super(SysUiState.initial()) {
    setInitTheme();
  }`
set InitTheme works with shared prefs but its delayed because await and async... so I got a exception NullCheckOperator

Comment: I solved it by myself with provider... :D Using provider inside Bloc lmao. I guess this is illegal. But atleast it works :D 
 `final isDarkModeOn = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context, listen: false).isSystemModeOn;
      final isSystemModeOn = Provider.of<ThemeService>(context, listen: false).isDarkModeOn;`

and then the same approach like you inside my Constructor :D

Comment: great job Fabian!